# Using jQuery scrollTop with Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-animate, scrolltop

So, I'm trying to use the jQuery animate to make a "scroll to top" button with a wordpress theme. I've been at this for a few hours with no luck. Here's the snippet of the JS:

```
 < script type = "text/javascript" > (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#back-top").hide();
            $(function () {
                $(window).scroll(function () {
                    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                        $('#back-top').fadeIn();
                    } else {
                        $('#back-top').fadeOut();
                    }
                });
                $('#back-top a').click(function () {
                    $('body,html').animate({
                        scrollTop : 0
                    }, 800);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        });
    });
(jQuery);
<  / script >
```

Here's my markup:

```
<p id="back-top"><a href="#top">&uarr;</a></p>
```

It's worth noting that the jQuery and other junks get called a few lines before the aforementioned piece of JS code.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://tambnguyen.com/wp-includes/js/prototype.js?ver=1.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://tambnguyen.com/wp-includes/js/scriptaculous/wp-scriptaculous.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://tambnguyen.com/wp-includes/js/scriptaculous/effects.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://tambnguyen.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, here's where I got the snippet from. I had to modify a few things to make it work. It's safe to say my JS skills are next to nothing. http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/animated-scroll-to-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sweet! I was able to reverse engineer a few other snippets from other Places. It works now.

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(function () {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery("#back-top").hide();
            jQuery(function () {
                jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
                    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                        jQuery('#back-top').fadeIn();
                    } else {
                        jQuery('#back-top').fadeOut();
                    }
                });
                jQuery('#back-top a').click(function () {
                    jQuery('body,html').animate({
                        scrollTop : 0
                    }, 800);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

use [event.preventDefault](http://jqapi.com/#p=event.preventDefault)

```
jQuery('#back-top').click(function() {
    jQuery('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 800);
    return false;
});​
```

Comment: what errors are you running into ? have you checked your console ?

Comment: Yes and yes. Looks like that function is called twice total after the whole web page is loaded. Should I add it somewhere else?

Comment: Looks like your latest version doesn't work either. $('#back-top a').click(function(event){event.preventDefault();$('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},800);return false;});?